# Which license keys are required for Experience Commerce?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, licensing

My client has a license for Sitecore Experience Commerce. Initially it didn't work, turns out the license key needed updating. Sitecore sent them this:

[image]

My question is; is this one key enough to run Commerce on 8.x and 9.x instances?

According to: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/911240 - two license keys are connected to Commerce

- Sitecore.CommerceServer.Runtime
- Sitecore.CommerceServer.Integrated

So it looks to me like one key is missing from the license. Or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the KB article hasn't been updated in a while and isn't correct for the 9.x series. The keys you require are as follows:

**8.x Series**

- Sitecore.CommerceServer.Runtime
- Sitecore.CommerceServer.Integrated
- Sitecore.Commerce.Connect

**9.x Series**

- Sitecore.Commerce.Connect

There is currently no license check for the 9.x series engine functionality just for the  Connect license key mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. So the key given to my client is in error then; given it holds only `Integrated` and not `Runtime`. It is meant to work on both 8.x and 9.x instances.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to run both 8.x & 9.x series sites you will need all 3 of the keys above.